# rectangle as textbox in canvas for html5

Tags: html

could anyone tell me whether can we make a rectangle box as input type such as textbox inside the canvas using html5.Please share your views.

Comment: Do you know what an [Event Listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) is?

Answer (score 0):

although I haven't tried, I can't see why you couldn't have an HTML  element over top of a canvas. Just set the 'position' style of the input element to 'relative' and adjust so that it appears over the canvas.

If that doesn't work, then on the canvas you can draw anything - it just takes more work.

Comment: You should be able to position an html element over the canvas using CSS.